# Why does my braces shows error?

Tags: java

[image]

[image]

Hello everyone. Today i started writting a code so i could open second activity while i am pressing on the button. And i am keep getting the "{}" brace errors. I also created manifest "android:name=".activity2">" But i can't find the way how should i fix my braces to stop showing error? I uplauded some pictures so you could see a bit better what's the problem. Maybe there is way easier way to open the second activity with the button? Any tips to fix the problem? Thank you :)

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button imeageTextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imeageTextBtn);
    assert imeageTextBtn != null;
    imeageTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), activity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello! Would you mind adding code instead of screenshots?

Comment: Okei, and i am getting errors on last 2 braces

Comment: If you use some IDE, remember that you can usually just hover your mouse over the code underlined with red, to see the explanation of why compiler thinks it's an error.

Comment: I did this, but I couldnt understand what was the explanation :D

Comment: please tell us what errors you get

Comment: The problem is solved! Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `imeageTextBtn.setOnclick....`, you need to add a `);` after the `}`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button imeageTextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imeageTextBtn);
    assert imeageTextBtn != null;
    imeageTextBtn.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: @Tadas So, you need to pass an instance of a `new View.OnClickListener()` to the act as a `listener` for when the `imeageTextBtn` is clicked. This code snippet creates a new `View.OnClickListener` that will launch a new intent, and attaches it as the handler for your button.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling the `setOnClickListener` method. so it needs a closing `)` and a semicolon.

```
imeageTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), activity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
```